# Сменить директорию по умолчанию в PowerShell

Tags: cmd, powershell

Когда запускаю PS по умолчанию попадаю в директорию юзера и каждый раз приходится писать

```
cd ../../openserver/domains
```

в cmd то же самое (наверно, это очевидно). Как можно этот момент взять под контроль? мало понимаю в терминалах

Comment: Измените рабочую папку в ярлыке запуска PowerShell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все подтягивается из профайла PS. Нужно создать и настроить свой профайл.

Для создания профиля PowerShell

1. Создайте папку в папке `Мои документы` под названием `WindowsPowerShell`
2. Создайте файл с именем `profile.ps1` внутри этой папки
3. Добавьте любые необходимые команды инициализации в этот файл и сохраните его
4. Каждый раз, когда вы запускаете `PowerShell`, сценарий профиля будет выполнен

в этот файл можно добавить переход в нужную директорию

Подробнее в `Get-Help about_profiles`

Comment: большое спасибо, очень помогло. В созданном файле прописал set-location path/to/dir/ и потом запустил консоль от администратора, чтобы разрешить локально выполнять скрипты Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned